# Rails 5 - Best way to hold onto params for creating associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the scenario to illustrate my question. I have 2 models:

```
# models/post.rb

belongs_to :user
validates_presence_of :comment
```

And we have a devise model called Users

```
# models/user.rb

has_many :posts
```

What I would like to achieve:

Person comes to the website, is able to create a `Post`, after creating the `Post`, they are prompted to create an account. After creating the account, the `Post` that they just created would be associated to the `User` they just created.

Usually i'd make use of routes to hold the `params[:id]` which can be accessed in the controller method. For example the URL may look something like this:

`www.foo.com/foo/new/1`

And then I can do this:

```
# foo_controller.rb

def new
  @foo = Foo.new
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
end
```

And in the view I can simply access `@parent` and use a hidden field to fill the parent ID.

But when routing through so many different pages (such as creating a Devise User), how do I hold onto the parent/child ID such that I can still create that association?

Comment: You can store the `post_id` in the session so that you can retrieve it when the user signs up

Answer (score 2):

Using an hidden field or the route to store the id, with no authorization in the process, would not be secure. What if I just use the browser inspector and change the value of the id ? Your cool post would be mine.

What you could do is, for instance, add a field called `guest_id` to the Post, in which the value is unique (like `SecureRandom.uuid`), and also store that value in the session.

Thus, after the user is created, you could do something like that

```
if (post = Post.find_by(guest_id: session[:guest_id])).present?
  post.update(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: If i'm using sessions, why still the need to go through `guest_id`? Anyway, thanks for pointing that out. I'd definitely fix it. And also sessions would likely solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: To me, this looks better solution than using session. This way user can create as many posts (by opening different tabs) before creating account.